# how can i launch an EMR Cluster using putty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

Have created an Elastic Map reduce Cluster  and made a note of the host name and generated a  key . When i tried to login i am getting a timeout error .Please help me to log in

Answer (score 1):

make sure the master node's security group allow SSH using port 22 by allowing inbound connection for that port